# Runaway argument in algorithm

Tags: errors, algorithms

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Partial Sum Update Algorithm}\label{alg:usline}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State $\mathcal{N}^*\gets$ bitreverse$(\mathcal{N})$
\If{$i(s)=0$}\Comment{The $s^{th}$ LSB in the binary representation of i is $0$.}
\If{$s=\log _2N - 1$ or$ i_{(\log _{2}N - 1):(s+1)} = \mathcal{N}_{(\log _{2}N - 2):s}^*$
\Endif
\Endif

\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

The above produces "runaway argument". Any ideas why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a missing closing brace in the last `\If` (the first opening brace is not balanced); in the code below I added it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Partial Sum Update Algorithm}\label{alg:usline}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State $\mathcal{N}^*\gets$ bitreverse$(\mathcal{N})$
\If{$i(s)=0$}\Comment{The $s^{th}$ LSB in the binary representation of i is $0$.}
\If{$s=\log _2N - 1$ or $ i_{(\log _{2}N - 1):(s+1)} = \mathcal{N}_{(\log _{2}N - 2):s}^*}$
\EndIf
\EndIf
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note also that the right syntax is `\EndIf` and not `\Endif` (at least if `algpseudocode` is being used).